# Find how many lines for each file format in a dataset using dplyr verbs

Tags: r, statistics, dplyr

I need to use 'group_by' and 'summarise' (part of dplyr package) to find how many lines there are for each type of file in a dataset. I'm trying to understand how this works because I need to use the result for other things later.
I tried something like this:

````
```{r problem}
grouped_files <- group_by(files_ENCODE, V5)
files_types <- summarise(grouped_files, V5)
```
````

With V5 being the column with the file format and files_ENCODE the dataset with everything in it.
I've never used R before and even my friend Google couldn't help me learn how to use those two functions. Please help! :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(123)
file_data <- data.frame(V5 = sample(c("format_1", "format_2", "format_3"), 20, replace = TRUE))
```

You can simply do this with `table`:

```
table(file_data)
file_data
format_1 format_2 format_3 
       6        6        8
```

But if it hast to be `dplyr` do the following:

```
file_data %>% group_by(V5) %>% summarise(n = n())
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

        V5 n()
1 format_1   6
2 format_2   6
3 format_3   8
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfecty! I simply didn't know how to write any of this.

If I may ask an other question, like I said I have to use this for something else: a graph. I'm able to use ggplot (I got the package and used the library) but when I try to add information to it with "geom_bar", it gives me an error. Here's what I used:
    ```{r problem2}
    graph <- ggplot(data = types_fichiers, aes(x = V5, y = n()))
    graph + geom_bar()
    ```

error in n() : This function should not be called directly

Comment: Try `ggplot(data = file_data_n, aes(x = V5, y = n)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")`